# php fwrite - variable with ; does not change file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fwrite

I'm trying to change a javascript file without having to connect via ftp. Therefore i'm using a textarea, where you fill the code in, submit it, and then the content of the textbox is saved to a file on the server (here called ender.js) .

here's my html, javascript and php (i'm using jquery)

html:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="result" rows="50" cols="150"></textarea> 
    <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

javascript:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        //alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'opener.php',
          data: {test: $('#result').val()},
          success: function() {
            $('#result').load('js/ender.js');
            alert('Load was performed.');
          },
          error: function() {
            alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \n'+'error:\n' + xhr.responseText );
          }

        });
    });
```

php:

```
<?php
    //echo $_POST['test'];
    $fp = fopen('js/ender.js', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['test']);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

if the textarea contains a ; (point-comma) the file does not change. Why is that?

**edit **

The mistake was in the javascript file.

```
data: {test: $('#result').val()},
```

should have been

```
data: {'test': $('#result').val()},
```

however I still have an issue if the textarea contains a point-comma ";"

Comment: Are you sure you have given write permissions to the user the web server is running as (usually www-data on unices) over js/ender.js on the server? You don't check $fp is non-null.

Comment: i'm 100% certain that the write permissions are ok. (i've edited the post a bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surly because it is cached in your browser. I had similar problems. Try to change the filename with a random name or with a parameter like `js/ender.js?rnd=123123`

Comment: or you can add ajax parameter cache:false

Answer (score 0):

IMO: This is a better way to do it:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
    <textarea name="result" id="result" rows="50" cols="150"></textarea> 
    <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'opener.php',
      data: $('#myform').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        $('#result').load('js/ender.js');
        alert('Load was performed.');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \n'+'error:\n' + xhr.responseText );
      }

    });
});
```